# Toolbar navigation icon size is too big

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Navigation drawer icon is too big. I want it small.
on create I am doing this :

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);

  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Actual size of icon:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy8ln.png)

but I want it small.

Comment: what is the size of image??

Comment: for all size device you use same size?

Comment: for different device you need different size

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html